# The code I wrote about dart stream gives me a null value whenever I work in the terminal

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, stream, flutter-test

Every time I run the code I wrote, the terminal does not return a value to me. I did not understand problem

```
   import 'dart:async';

main() {
  functionforStreamController();

  myStreamController.stream.listen((e) => print("Selam"));
}

StreamController myStreamController = StreamController();

functionforStreamController() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    myStreamController.sink.add(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not return a value"? Your headline says "gives me a null value". Which is it? And where do you return *any* value at all? Do you mean you see no output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, remove asterisk*

```
import 'dart:async';


StreamController myStreamController = StreamController();

main() {
  myStreamController.stream.listen((e) => print("Selam"));
  functionforStreamController();
}


functionforStreamController() async {
  print("functionforStreamController");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    myStreamController.sink.add(i);
  }
}
```